# DTML: How to prevent formatting loss

Tags: python, html

I have a DTML document which only contains:

```
<dtml-var public_blast_results>
```

and displays when i view it as:

```
YP_001336283    100.00    345    0    0     23     367    23     367    0.0    688
```

When I edit the DTML page for example just adding a header like:

```
<h3>Header</h3>
<dtml-var public_blast_results>
```

The "public_blast_results" loeses its formatting and displayes as:

```
Header
YP_001336283 100.00 345 0 0 23 367 23 367 0.0 688
```

Is there a way for maintaining the formatting? public_blast_results is a python function which just simply reads the contents of a file and returns it.

Answer (score 2):

This is nothing to do with DTML - it's a basic issue with HTML, which is that it ignores whitespace. If you want to preserve it, you need to wrap the content with `<pre>`.

```
<pre><dtml-var public_blast_results></pre>
```